# Trying to dualboot Zorin OS but there's no boot option in BIOS

Tags: linux, bios, multi-boot, zorin

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T430, and I'm trying to dualboot Zorin OS, but I'm not sure what to do next.

There's no boot option. There's startup, but I'm not sure if that's right.

Comment: The BIOS will show you the available devices.  If you put Zorin on one or more other partitions of the same hard drive as Windows, you'll still see that hard drive in the BIOS.  When you power up, you should quickly see the GRUB menu, which will let you pick which OS to boot.  If that isn't happening, we'll need to figure out exactly what you did, so please try it and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Did you (or the setup) install a bootloader (e.g. Grub, Syslinux?) If you're not sure then it probably did unless you told it to not.

Then in BIOS you would set Startup to your hard drive, and then Grub/Syslinux would show when you started the computer, allowing you to choose an operating system